# Expresión regular que siempre ha de cumplirse

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando verificar si una cadena tiene este formato: `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX`.

La expresión que me ha funcionado ha sido la siguiente: `let patron = /^\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}$/;` (4 "caracteres", seguidos de un guión, seguido de 4 "caracteres"). Digo caracteres entre comillas porque el \w abarca más que eso. También la idea es que no contenga el guión bajo (*_*), que tengo entendido que el \w lo incluye, pero ese es otro tema.

Lo que quería era una forma más elegante de resolver este problema. He pensado algo del siguiente estilo:

`let patron = /-|^(?=\w{4}(?=-|$)){4}/;`

La idea era un fragmento de string iniciado por guión (o el inicio de la string en sí), seguido de 4 "caracteres", seguido de guión (o final de string); todo esto 4 veces.

El problema es que no funciona, y creo que tiene que ver con que detecta el primer fragmento que se cumple y deja de mirar los demás (con el flag 'g' tampoco funciona).

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Porqué sobrecargar la expresión regular? ¿Qué significa *elegante* y de qué forma es preferible a *funcional*?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Simplemente es por hacer las cosas de forma distinta, pero te pongo un ejemplo donde la segunda es mejor que la primera. Imagina que no son 4 repeticiones, si no son N (si N=2 seria XXXX-XXXX, si vale 5 XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX...) en ese caso simplemente con cambiar el '4' por una variable ya terminarias. En el primer caso habría que usar un bucle estilo `for (let x = 0; x < n; x++) patron += '\\w{4}' + '-';`.

Comment: @RogerMirandaPerez no creo que se pueda hacer una expresion regular dinamica de ese estilo. simplemente creo que es imposible.

Comment: No te gusta `^\w{4}(-\w{4}){3}$`? El problema con `(?=\w{4}(?=-|$)){4}` es que una prevision (lookahead) `(?=...)` verifica pero no avanza (por lo cual se llama afirmación de ancho cero), así que verifica los mismos cinco carácteres cuatro veces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La elegancia está en el ojo del espectador, y a mí no me parece muy elegante. Pero creo que funciona, y evita repetición:

```regex
^(\w{4}(?:-(?!$)|(?=$))){4}$
```

[En vivo, en Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/BkQdl1/1)

`(?:-(?!$)|(?=$)))` quiere decir "o un guión no seguido por el fin de la cadena (`-(?!$)`) o la nada justo antes del fin de la cadena (`(?=$)`)".

No me queda completamente claro que quieres decir con "caracter". Si estás buscando "`\w` menos subrayo", podrías poner `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Como `\w`, coincida solo con códigos ASCII (es decir, sin á o ñ, por ejemplo). Si quieres coincidir con cualquier símbolo alfabético o numerico en cualquier idioma, podrías intentar `[\p{L}\p{N}]` aunque solo funcionaría en versiones recientes de JS, y tendrías que indicar que la regex está por Unicode, con la flag `u`:

```
/^([\p{L}\p{N}]{4}(?:-(?!$)|(?=$))){4}$/u
```

Comment: Eso es justo a lo que me refería. Una última cosa, hay alguna diferencia entre "?:" y "?=" ?

Comment: @roger: `(?:` es solo un paréntesis. A diferencia de `()`, no captura la coincidencia, lo cual podría ser un poquito más rápido. Por eso, tengo el hábito de usarlo para indicar que no voy a hacer referencia a la cadena capturada. Por otro lado, `(?=` es una afirmación de ancho cero: es decir, verifica que los próximos carácteres coinciden, pero no avanza sobre ellos; el próximo elemento tendrá que coincidir con las mismas caracteres. Así que son muy diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es la siguiente:

```
(?!-)(?:(?:^|-)\w{4}){4}$
```

Es 3 caracteres más corta que la alternativa de rici.

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/BkQdl1/4).

Sin embargo, creo que estas estrategias para evitar repeticiones sólo tienen sentido cuando lo que se va a repetir es una expresión más o menos compleja. `\w{4}` es una expresión muy simple y no tiene sentido complicar la expresión regular intentando evitar la repetición.

Para mi, la expresión regular adecuada para este requerimiento sería:

```
^\w{4}(?:-\w{4}){3}$
```

De hecho, de esta manera es incluso más corto, pese a que tenemos la "repetición" de `\w{4}`.

Es más, esta última forma es bastante común a la hora de parsear información, y es muy utilizada en [gramáticas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica_(aut%C3%B3mata)).

Incluso aunque la expresión que se repite fuera compleja, podrías "montar" una expresión regular a partir de variables, y quedaría una expresión mucho más legible.

Por ejemplo, en javascript:

```js
var expresion = "[0-9]BLABLA[0-9]___BLA_12345_BLABLABLA___999"; // Lo que queremos repetir separado por guiones
 
var re = new RegExp(`^${expresion}(?:-${expresion}){3}$`,"g");
 
var donde_buscar = "1BLABLA1___BLA_12345_BLABLABLA___999-1BLABLA1___BLA_12345_BLABLABLA___999-1BLABLA1___BLA_12345_BLABLABLA___999-1BLABLA1___BLA_12345_BLABLABLA___999";
 
console.log(donde_buscar.match(re));
```

Answer (score -1):

Le he estado dando vueltas y he logrado una forma enfocada de una forma distinta, pero igual de funcional:

```
var n = 4;
var size = n*5 - 1;
var txt = "1234-1234-1234-1235";
var patron = /(?:[A-Za-z1-9]{4}(?:-|$))+/y;

txt.match(patron);

// ¿coincide con el patrón?
console.log(patron.lastIndex === size);
```